# Parallel.For error

Tags: c#, datetime, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

Im trying to pare a DateTime in a Parallel.For:

part of the code:

```
        public void LoadLogFile(String fileName) {
        //Thread.CurrentThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Lowest;

        String currentFile = "";
        if (fileName.Contains("Compass")) {
            currentFile = "Compass";
            CompassLogLoadCompleted = false;
            compassLogCollection.Clear();
            compassLogCollection.AsParallel();
        } else if (fileName.Contains("")) {
            currentFile = "CoreService";
            CoreServiceLogLoadCompleted = false;
            coreServiceLogCollection.Clear();
            ;
            compassLogCollection.AsParallel();
        } else {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Wrong File");
        }

        if (fileName.Contains("CoreService") ||
            fileName.Contains("Compass")) {
            int numberOfSingleLineLog = 0;
            int numberOfmultipleLineLog = 0;
            String[] lines = new string[] {};

            String temp = "";
            string[] parts;
            DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();
            LoggingLvl loggingLvl = new LoggingLvl();
            LoggingLvl.ELoggingLvl eLoggingLvl = new LoggingLvl.ELoggingLvl();
            int id = 0;
            char[] delimiters = new[] {' '};
            string threadId = "";
            string loggingMessage;
            string loggingMessage2 = "";
            //string dateAndTimestamp = "";
            int ff = 0;

            // Read the File and add it to lines string
            try {
                swCompass.Start();
                lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
                swCompass.Stop();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                CompassLogLoadCompleted = true;
                CoreServiceLogLoadCompleted = true;
                Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

            swCompass.Reset();
            swCompass.Start();
            // Adding the objects to the collections

            //compassLogCollection.EnableNotify = false;

            Parallel.For(0, lines.Count(), j => {
                                               //for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count(); i++) {
                                               string dateAndTimestamp = "";
                                               if (!CompassLogLoadCompleted || !CoreServiceLogLoadCompleted) {
                                                   try {
                                                       if (SingleLined(ref lines, j)) {
                                                           parts = lines[j].Split(delimiters,
                                                                                  StringSplitOptions.
                                                                                      RemoveEmptyEntries);
                                                           numberOfSingleLineLog++;
                                                           foreach (string t in parts) {
                                                               switch (ff) {
                                                                   case 0:
                                                                       dateAndTimestamp = t;
                                                                       break;
                                                                   case 1:
                                                                       dateAndTimestamp += " " + t.Replace(",", ".");
                                                                       dateTime = DateTime.Parse(dateAndTimestamp);
                                                                       //dateTime = new DateTime();
                                                                       dateAndTimestamp = "";
                                                                       break;
                                                                   case 2:
                                                                       eLoggingLvl = loggingLvl.ParseLoggingLvl(t);
                                                                       break;
                                                                   case 3:
                                                                       threadId = t;
                                                                       break;

                                                                   default:
                                                                       temp += t;
                                                                       break;
                                                               }

                                                               ff++;
                                                           }

                                                           loggingMessage = temp;

                                                           temp = "";
                                                           ff = 0;
                                                           id++;
                                                           loggingLvl = new LoggingLvl(eLoggingLvl);

                                                           if (fileName.Contains("Compass")) {
                                                               //CompassLogLoadPercent = ((double) numberOfSingleLineLog/lines.Count())*100;

                                                               CompassLogData cLD =
                                                                   new CompassLogData(
                                                                       (numberOfSingleLineLog +
                                                                        numberOfmultipleLineLog),
                                                                       dateTime,
                                                                       loggingLvl, threadId,
                                                                       loggingMessage);

                                                               //await addRoCompassLogCollectionAsync(cLD);
                                                               compassLogCollection.Add(cLD);
                                                           } else if (fileName.Contains("CoreService")) {
                                                               CoreServiceLogData cSLD =
                                                                   new CoreServiceLogData(
                                                                       (numberOfSingleLineLog +
                                                                        numberOfmultipleLineLog),
                                                                       dateTime,
                                                                       loggingLvl,
                                                                       threadId,
                                                                       loggingMessage);
                                                               //await addRoCoreServiceCollectionAsync(cSLD);
                                                               coreServiceLogCollection.Add(cSLD);
                                                           } else {
                                                               Console.Out.WriteLine("File Not recognizable ");
                                                           }

                                                           //Console.Out.WriteLine(loggingMessage);
                                                           //loggingMessage = "";
                                                       } else {
                                                           loggingMessage2 += lines[j];
                                                           loggingMessage2 += "\n";
                                                           //parts[i] += lines[i];
                                                           //parts[i] += "\n";

                                                           if (NextLineIsANumber(ref lines, j)) {
                                                               numberOfmultipleLineLog++;
                                                               //Console.Out.WriteLine(loggingMessage2);
                                                               parts = loggingMessage2.Split(delimiters,
                                                                                             StringSplitOptions.
                                                                                                 RemoveEmptyEntries);
                                                               foreach (string t in parts) {
                                                                   switch (ff) {
                                                                       case 0:
                                                                           dateAndTimestamp = t;
                                                                           break;
                                                                       case 1:
                                                                           dateAndTimestamp += " " +
                                                                                               t.Replace(",", ".");
                                                                           //dateTime = DateTime.Parse(dateAndTimestamp);
                                                                           dateTime = new DateTime();
                                                                           dateAndTimestamp = "";
                                                                           break;
                                                                       case 2:
                                                                           eLoggingLvl =
                                                                               loggingLvl.ParseLoggingLvl(t);
                                                                           break;
                                                                       case 3:
                                                                           threadId = t;
                                                                           break;

                                                                       default:
                                                                           temp += t;
                                                                           break;
                                                                   }

                                                                   ff++;
                                                               }

                                                               loggingMessage = temp;

                                                               temp = "";
                                                               ff = 0;
                                                               id++;
                                                               loggingLvl = new LoggingLvl(eLoggingLvl);

                                                               if (fileName.Contains("Compass")) {
                                                                   CompassLogData cLD =
                                                                       new CompassLogData(
                                                                           (numberOfSingleLineLog +
                                                                            numberOfmultipleLineLog),
                                                                           dateTime,
                                                                           loggingLvl, threadId,
                                                                           loggingMessage);

                                                                   //await addRoCompassLogCollectionAsync(cLD);
                                                                   compassLogCollection.Add(cLD);
                                                               } else if (fileName.Contains("CoreService")) {
                                                                   CoreServiceLogData cSLD =
                                                                       new CoreServiceLogData(
                                                                           (numberOfSingleLineLog +
                                                                            numberOfmultipleLineLog),
                                                                           dateTime,
                                                                           loggingLvl,
                                                                           threadId,
                                                                           loggingMessage);

                                                                   //await addRoCoreServiceCollectionAsync(cSLD);
                                                                   coreServiceLogCollection.Add(cSLD);
                                                               } else {
                                                                   Console.Out.WriteLine("File Not recognizable ");
                                                               }

                                                               loggingMessage2 = "";
                                                           }
                                                       }
                                                   } catch (Exception e) {
                                                       Console.Out.WriteLine("Shit Happens");
                                                       Console.Out.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                                                   }

                                                   if (currentFile == "Compass") {
                                                       //CompassLogLoadPercent =
                                                       //    ((double)
                                                       //     i
                                                       //     /lines.Count())*100;

                                                       CompassLogLoadPercent = ((double)
                                                                                j
                                                                                /lines.Count())*100;
                                                   } else if (currentFile == "CoreService") {
                                                       CoreServiceLogLoadPercent =
                                                           ((double)
                                                            j
                                                            /lines.Count())*100;
                                                   }
                                               }
                                           });
            //}
            //compassLogCollection.EnableNotify = true;
            //compassLogCollection.notifyAll();

            if (currentFile == "Compass") {
                Console.Out.WriteLine("Compass TIME: " + swCompass.Elapsed);
            } else {
                Console.Out.WriteLine("CoreSevice TIME: " + swCompass.Elapsed);
            }

            if (currentFile == "Compass") {
                CompassLogLoadCompleted = true;
                Console.Out.WriteLine("Compass LOADING DONE");
            } else if (currentFile == "CoreService") {
                CoreServiceLogLoadCompleted = true;
                Console.Out.WriteLine("CoreService LOADING DONE");
            }
            //CoreServiceLogLoadCompleted = true;
            Console.Out.WriteLine("numberOfSingleLineLog: " +
                                  numberOfSingleLineLog);
            Console.Out.WriteLine("numberOfmultipleLineLog: " +
                                  numberOfmultipleLineLog);
            Console.Out.WriteLine("numberOfLogs: " +
                                  (numberOfSingleLineLog +
                                   numberOfmultipleLineLog));
            Console.Out.WriteLine("");
            //}
        }
    }
```

but i get the following Exception:

```
   at System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles styles)
   at System.DateTime.Parse(String s)
   at LogViewerV1.LogSession.<>c__DisplayClass3.<LoadLogFile>b__0(Int32 i) in                 c:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Pallas informatik\LogViewerV1\LogViewerV1\src\LogSession.cs:line 169
   A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.d
```

If I run this in a ordinary for loop i dont get any exception and everything works fine.
any Idea how to fix This?

Comment: Where is `parts` defined?  And `temp`?  For `Parallel.For` to work, depending on any singular state outside of the `Parallel.For` is probably going to fall down.

Comment: What does this have to do with TPL? Your input string is invalid, as the message tells you.

Comment: if i run this in the for loop, everything is Fine...

Comment: This could be a problem with culture. What is the culture of the original thread and the `Parallel.For()` threads? What kind of application is this?

Comment: What is the actual input string, both in the parallel loop and in the non-parallel loop?

Comment: I have edit the code, if U wanna look at it.

Answer (score 0):

FormatException would indicate that the input DateTime is not in the expected format. You should be using the overloads of DateTime.Parse which allow you to specify the DateTypeStyle.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse.aspx#Parse1_Example

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you somehow set the culture of the main thread. But culture is not copied to any other thread, so the background threads that run (parts of) the `Parallel.For()` loop have different culture.

What you should do is to explicitly specify the culture to use:

```
DateTime.Parse(dateAndTimestamp, theCorrectCulture)
```